# Pulling data from another page XAML C#

Tags: c#, xaml, button, listbox

I have a project where on first page button gets text basing on listbox selection. 
Then, on the 2nd page I have another button that should get the last selected value from page 1.

Is there a way to exchange data between pages?

Here is some code I use:

```
var x = (itemsControl.SelectedItem as ItemsData);
           firstElement.Content = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", x.value0, x.value1, x.value2, x.value3, x.value4);


        object CPU = firstElement.Content;
```

firstElement is being sent to the button firstElement using binding.

then I store the content in CPU object, I would like to share this content with another page.

I tried the solution from the link below. Unfortunately I didn't get it to work. Now, on the Main Page when I select item from listbox, it's value is not sent to button above, instead, when clicked on listbox item I get redirected to the second Page immediately. No data is passed.

Am I missing something?

I managed to pass data from Main Page using:

```
private void Button2Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        object CPU = firstElement.Content;
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Menu2), CPU);

    }
```

I am still unable to retrieve it within Page 2. On Page 2 I have button that has the same name as on Main Page - firstElement.

I would like to retrieve passed data within this button.

Within Second Page I put:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs c)
    {
        firstElement.Content = c;
    }
```

Upon opening Second Page, the button displays this:

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs
```

Comment: I will verify your link. thank oyu

Comment: it doesnt work.